# NSLog statement does not print my object

Tags: objective-c

If i add an object to a property "dreamsArr", which is NSMutableArray:

```
@synthesize dreamsArr;

-(void) viewDidLoad
{
    Dream *d1 = [[Dream alloc] init];
    d1.title = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"my 1st dream"];

    self.dreamsArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    [self.dreamsArr addObject:d1];

    Dream *dr = [self.dreamsArr objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *title=dr.title;

    const char *chTitle = [title UTF8String]; 
    NSLog(@"%s", chTitle);
}
```

Why does NSLog print "null"?
when i trace this code, after [self.dreamsArr addObject:d1] ,  dreamsArr still empty, why?

Comment: Looks fine to me, except that you're leaking stuff, also no need for char magic, just NSLog(@"title:%@", dr.title) and see if it's also null.

Comment: Is it possible that you have an own implementation of `init` in your `Dream` class? If so: do you end it with `return self`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem was in the other part of code

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using char array placeholder (`%s`) in `NSLog` statement instead of object's which should be used to print `NSString`. Try this:

```
NSLog("%@", chTitle);
```

Also, unless you're using ARC, you have a leak on 2nd and 4th  lines of `viewDidLoad` method.

The line below has a leak

```
d1.title = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"my 1st dream"];
```

The leak comes from the assignment of title property which (i presume) is `@property` with `retain` modifier. The `alloc` calls creates an object with +1 retain count while assignment makes it +2. Since you don't balance it out with `release` call below in the method - you get a leak. Same goes for the 4th line:

```
self.dreamsArr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

which creates leak in the very same manner.

Leaks are valid only if you're not releasing your `dreamsArr` instance variable in `viewDidUnload` method and `title` instance variable in the `dealloc` method of your `Dream` class.

Comment: thnks, but it's all about deallocated of properties. Why dreamsArr still empty after [self.dreamsArr addObject:d1]

Comment: I don't know. You don't check for the emptiness of array, but for emptiness of `d1.title` property. Please be more specific in your question.